# How to upsert into concurrent map while iterating over regular map?

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency

I need to have a map of `string` as key and unique (no dupes) `int64` array as value so I decided to use something like below  so that value can act as a set.

```
var customerCatalog = make(map[string]map[int64]bool)
```

Above map is populated with some data in it. Now I am trying to populate my [concurrent map](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) in golang by reading above regular `customerCatalog` map but I am getting error:

```
for k, v := range customerCatalog {
  r.customerCatalog.Upsert(k, v, func(exists bool, valueInMap interface{}, newValue interface{}) interface{} {
    typedNewValue := newValue.([]int64)
    if !exists {
      return typedNewValue
    }
    typedValueInMap := valueInMap.([]int64)
    return append(typedValueInMap, typedNewValue...)
  })
}
```

This is the error I am getting. I am using upsert method as shown [here](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map/blob/master/concurrent_map.go#L56)

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[int64]bool, not []int64
```

What is wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue would be as follows ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/cUW1Lab4Axb)):

```golang
conMap := cmap.New()

v := map[int64]bool{}
updateItemFn := func(exist bool, valueInMap interface{}, newValue interface{}) interface{} {
    _ = newValue.([]int64)
    return nil
}

conMap.Upsert("foo", v, updateItemFn)
```

Note: I have stripped out the loop etc because that is irrelevant to the panic. However you should note that because the loop iterates over a `map[string]map[int64]bool`the type of `v` will be `map[int64]bool`.

The [`Upsert`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map#ConcurrentMap.Upsert) function looks up the key in the map and then passes it and the `value` you passed in to the function.

So your function is receiving a `map[int64]bool` and the first thing it does is to assert that this is a `[]int64` (which will fail because it's not). To fix this you need to convert the `map[int64]bool` into a `[]int64`. This could be done before calling the `Upsert` or within your implementation of `UpsertCb` as shown here ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Xc3iKlIaEjk)):

```golang
conMap := cmap.New()
conMap.Set("foo", []int64{5, 6})

v := map[int64]bool{
    1: true,
}

updateItemFn := func(exist bool, valueInMap interface{}, newValue interface{}) interface{} {
    m := newValue.(map[int64]bool)
    a := make([]int64, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        a = append(a, k)
    }
    if valueInMap == nil { // New value!
        return a
    } else {
        typedValueInMap := valueInMap.([]int64)
        return append(typedValueInMap, a...)
    }
    return a
}

conMap.Upsert("foo", v, updateItemFn)

fmt.Println(conMap.Get("foo"))
```

The above has been kept simple to demonstrate the point; in reality you may want to add all of the values into a map so as to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. So you mean to say I just need to do [this](https://go.dev/play/p/Xhz2WPosgQu). Let me know if I got it right? And it will avoid duplicates values in an array for particular key right?

Comment: That will work but will not prevent duplicates. Consider what happens if the `conMap` entry includes a `3` and so does the new value (you combine the two so end up with two threes). A simple way to resolve this is [use a map](https://go.dev/play/p/e6KiTM6hGu1) (note: This edits the map you passed in which may be undesirable).

Comment: yeah that makes sense when you say `This edits the map you passed in which may be undesirable` you meant `v` map right?

Comment: Correct. That may be an issue if you use it for something else but if the map is created, and only used, for the `upsert` then it should be fine. However if `customerCatalog` is used elsewhere then you may want to copy the map.